# Does FireBase Cloud Messeging requires Play Services?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does FCM requires. that the user must have Play Services installed on his phone in order to receive notifications?

You see GCM do but now Im planning to move to FCM hoping it does not...how could I know before testing?

Comment: When updating to Firebase checkout [this](http://www.etivy.com/googleapiavailability-missed-with-firebase-messaging-9-4-0/) simply add compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.8.0'

Comment: Indeed it does. If you're looking for a push notification service for Android that does not depdend on Google Play Services, consider [Pushy](https://pushy.me/), a commercial product that does just that. Full disclosure - I work at Pushy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

See: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#switch_to_fcm_in_the_app-level_buildgradle

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

> FCM clients require devices running Android 4.4 or higher that also
> have the Google Play Store app installed, or an emulator running
> Android 4.4 with Google APIs. Note that you are not limited to
> deploying your Android apps through Google Play Store.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does. Firebase Cloud Messaging is just a rebrand of GCM.

More information in [GCM FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase requires Google Play Services 9.0.0 or newer in order to be used in you application. (This includes FCM).

This is listed as the first prerequisite in the Add Firebase to your Android Project document in the Get Started Guide:

Add Firebase to your Android Project

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Firebase SDK you are using, Google Play Services may or may not be required.

Read [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services) to check which Firebase SDKs require Google Play Services.