# FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission

Tags: android, firebase

My app keeps crashing but I can't figure out why.
Can someone please tell me

My Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.securitytechno2018"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
   android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 
'src/main/java/com/securitytechno2018/listeners'] }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My logcat:

```
    04-25 10:10:44.101 1621-1621/system_process I/InstallerConnection: connecting...

                                                                   [ 04-25 10:10:44.102  1302: 1302 I/         ]
                                                                   new connection
04-25 10:10:44.145 1621-1621/system_process I/InstallerConnection: disconnecting...

                                                                   [ 04-25 10:10:44.145  1302: 1302 E/         ]
                                                                   eof


                                                                   [ 04-25 10:10:44.145  1302: 1302 E/         ]
                                                                   failed to read size


                                                                   [ 04-25 10:10:44.145  1302: 1302 I/         ]
                                                                   closing connection
04-25 10:10:44.551 1621-1621/system_process I/InstallerConnection: connecting...

                                                                   [ 04-25 10:10:44.551  1302: 1302 I/         ]
                                                                   new connection
04-25 10:11:00.376 1621-1621/system_process W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
04-25 10:11:48.189 2633-2658/com.securitytechno2018 E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
04-25 10:11:48.252 2633-2633/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:11:48.256 2633-2633/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
04-25 10:11:48.311 2633-2633/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: onActivityCreated
04-25 10:11:49.476 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Collection enabled
04-25 10:11:49.476 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: App package, google app id: com.securitytechno2018, 1:702727695830:android:1ac1b0e480da2fe9
04-25 10:11:49.476 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
04-25 10:11:49.477 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
04-25 10:11:49.478 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                            adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.securitytechno2018
04-25 10:11:49.478 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
04-25 10:11:49.505 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Checking service availability
04-25 10:11:49.518 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 W/FA: Service invalid
04-25 10:11:49.521 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Using local app measurement service
04-25 10:11:49.561 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-25 10:11:51.294 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-25 10:11:51.297 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 77330
04-25 10:11:51.370 2633-2633/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is starting up
04-25 10:11:51.400 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1354703464960186567}]
04-25 10:11:51.434 2633-2633/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Bound to IMeasurementService interface
04-25 10:11:51.508 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-25 10:11:51.509 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connected to service
04-25 10:11:51.509 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
04-25 10:11:51.525 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 I/FA: This instance being marked as an uploader
04-25 10:11:51.617 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Nothing to upload or uploading impossible
04-25 10:11:51.685 2633-2671/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 2074818501
```

Comment: But why is there a Firebase instanceID error ?

Comment: I just checked and play services is not downloaded in my emulator and will this code work if play services is installed?

Comment: your device or emulator installed google play services

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422538/does-firebase-cloud-messeging-requires-play-services

Comment: @PeterHaddad Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download google play service sdk and add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in manifest if not added.

Answer (score 26):

Try running on real Device, the problem is related to emulators or genymotion virtual machines.

check that you have google play services installed.

Comment: I'm getting this on an older amazon fire tablet

Comment: Maybe you don't have google play services on this device, or you need to update them

Comment: I was just mentioning this because your answer states that this is related to emulators which I am not using.

Comment: yes you are right because sometimes on the emulator doesn't have the play services .me face the same issue on real time working correctly

Comment: Amazon devices don't have Google Play Services.

Comment: @manfcas Is it possible to manually install Google Play Services on Amazon devices?

Comment: @ctorx did you manage to make it work on Amazon Fire tablet ?

Comment: @TSR yes, I think so (https://www.theverge.com/2019/7/8/20681267/amazon-fire-tablet-google-apps-gmail-maps-drive-play-store-how-to-get).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while using Google Maps on my device. The problem was Google Map Service were not installed in my emulator.

> Simply add google play services on your emulator. It will clear your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its needed the real device you prefer real android device for check your build.you can use usb connect with android phone and debug mode you can also see error.